# How to show Vagrant box version used in a particular directory

Tags: vagrant

I have multiple Vagrant boxes, and would like to see what version of what box is running in which directory.
`vagrant box list` returns a global list of boxes:

```
puphpet/centos65-x64   (virtualbox, 1.2.1)
puphpet/centos65-x64   (virtualbox, 2.0)
```

`vagrant global-status` shows directories with providers:

```
id       name    provider   state    directory
--------------------------------------------------
a427238  default virtualbox poweroff /path/to/dir1
fa21751  default virtualbox running  /path/to/dir2
```

But how can I see which Vagrant box version is used in which directory?

Comment: I dont think vagrant can do that as this information is coming from the Vagrantfile and you can change that anytime so you can initialize with one box and later on change it to run with another box (if you upgrade os or other thing) you would need a script to read each of the Vagrant file and get the vm.box information

Comment: Thanks Frédéric!  Here are a couple of scripts I used to help determine which box a VM is using:  `grep -ir 'vm.box' path/to/vms 2>&-` and, if using VirtualBox, `VBoxManage list vms --long | egrep -i "(^Name:\s{8,})|(^Guest OS:\s)"`

Comment: nice job on the script !

Comment: Though, it still won't tell you the vagrant version of the box. Like `puphpet/centos65-x64   (virtualbox, 1.2.1)` as opposed to `puphpet/centos65-x64   (virtualbox, 2.0)` rather it just gives you something more generic like `Red Hat (64-bit)`. Thanks though.

Answer (score 12):

This data is possible to retrieve but is not exposed, as far as I know, through the Vagrant CLI. Take a look in `~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index` for Linux or macOS and I would assume it'd be something like `C:\Users\whoever\.vagrant.d\data\machine-index` on Windows.

You'll get some unformatted JSON which contains details on every machine Vagrant knows about. If you run the JSON through a pretty-printer/beautifier you'll get one of these for every machine:

```json
"d62342a255436211725abe8fd3c313ea": {
    "local_data_path": "/Users/whoever/mymachine/.vagrant",
    "name": "default",
    "provider": "virtualbox",
    "state": "poweroff",
    "vagrantfile_name": null,
    "vagrantfile_path": "/Users/whoever/mymachine",
    "updated_at": null,
    "extra_data": {
        "box": {
            "name": "ubuntu/xenial64",
            "provider": "virtualbox",
            "version": "20170706.0.0"
        }
    }
},
```

And the box information associated with your machine is right there. The `ubuntu/xenial64` box on the `virtualbox` provider version `20170706.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of an old thread, but I ran into this situation recently that matched the original request, and I discovered an answer that is not listed here:

The `vagrant box outdated` command lists the current box version number when it tests to see if there is a newer version of the box.

The caveat is that the `vagrant box outdated` command needs access to the internet to check the current version, which it also outputs.

I only discovered this after I had written this `bash` script that uses `jq` to search for the current directory in the `~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index` file.  I make no guarantees that this will work in your environment:

```
$ cat ~/scripts/vagrant_box_info.sh
#!/bin/bash

CUR_DIR=`pwd`

JQ_CMD='.machines|to_entries|map(select(.value.vagrantfile_path|test("'$CUR_DIR'$")))[].value.extra_data'

cat ~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index | jq "$JQ_CMD"

$ ~/scripts/vagrant_box_info.sh
{
  "box": {
    "name": "geerlingguy/centos7",
    "provider": "virtualbox",
    "version": "1.2.15"
  }
}
$
```

Answer (score 1):

building on kevin's answer, if you are using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) you can get most of what you need by parsing the json with:

```
cat ~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index | jq ".machines |to_entries[] | .value | .vagrantfile_path,.extra_data"
```

which gets me:

```
"/Users/myuser/kds2/chef/vagrant/test_bridged_192"
{
  "box": {
    "name": "opscode-ubuntu-14.04",
    "provider": "virtualbox",
    "version": "0"
  }
}
"/Users/myuser/kds2/chef/vagrant/testzero"
{
  "box": {
    "name": "opscode-ubuntu-14.04",
    "provider": "virtualbox",
    "version": "0"
  }
}
"/Users/myuser/kds2/wk/issues/fb230.bare_monit/vag"
{
  "box": {
    "name": "opscode-ubuntu-14.04",
    "provider": "virtualbox",
    "version": "0"
  }
}
```

Warning:  if you have removed the vm via something like `rm -rf .vagrant` manually, the `index` file may not reflect that.

However, if for example you `vagrant box remove opscode-ubuntu-14.04` then vagrant will realize that the box is not actually being used, will allow removal of the box and will update the index file accordingly.